# Software to check internet usage of computers connected through Wifi on Belkin Router

Tags: windows-7, network-monitor

We are getting many issues regarding Internet speed on our network; it is like someone is using the Internet heavily. We don't want to check each system manually for usage.

9 Pcs are connected on our network through the Wifi connection of a Belkin Router. I want to see data usage of each system connected to the router.

I don't want to upgrade the firmware of the router. The software should run on one single PC. We use Windows 7.

Comment: going to need to know some more details of the router.
Importantly weather it runs OpenWRT, and/or supports VLANs.
Or if it already reports this information on its web interface.
If none of these things are true, then it is not possible.
If either of the first two are true then it is only possible by going into some nitty gritty router stuff.

(Thoough there might be another way using packet sniffing. I'm not too clued up on that. I don't think it can work but i could be wrong).

Also might be worth telling the security  type (WEP etc) you are using for wifi

Answer (score 1):

One router-independent solution would be to run [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) (free, open source, cross-platform) in [promiscuous mode](http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/18259/capture-all-packets-in-promiscuous-mode) to receive all packets your wifi card sees whether they are addressed to the interface or not. I used to use the Wireless adapter Alfa AWUS036H to sniff around as for some Wi-Fi cards it's the pain to modify the drivers to allow the promiscuous mode (that was many years ago, I don't know about recent Wi-Fi cards).

Then once WireShark is sniffing, go to the [Statistics menu](http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/25575/sort-by-bandwidth-used-and-show-ip-addressnetwork-name) or analyze the pcap log with some other programs.

Comment: Thank you. Where can I see IP Addresses and Data Usage of all systems which are connected through Wifi Network ???

Comment: I think this is a fairly poor recommendation.  Assuming that the OP needs to monitor usage over longish periods of time,  Graphical collection tools are inappropriate.  Wireshark might be usable for analysis (after capturing with tcpdump), but it's probably not a good option.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your router has a facility to export this info, or you're prepared to put in firmware that will, then you probably cannot do what you want without rearranging your network.

If you don't want to mess with custom firmware in your router, then you will need to put your collection PC between your wireless network and your outgoing link.  That means you need separate devices for your ADSL router (or whatever you use for your external link) and for your internal wifi, with each of those connecting to your monitoring PC via ethernet cables.  Your monitoring PC would need to have two ethernet interfaces, and be able to route traffic between them.

Personally I would use Linux for this, but I expect there must be windows software which will do the job.